# click on spinner item and call asynctask of second spinner list item

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in which i need to fill spinner from one `webservice` and there are second spinner are also exist which fill after select first spinner item. second(spinner B) is depend on spinner A. i got list for A but problem with b spinner.

my basic requirement is when i select the item of spinner "A" it will load all item of Spinner "b" 
**here is code ::**

```
package com.CaribPay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Setting.CustomParser;

public class Register2 extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private Button BtnReg2Next;
    private EditText EdtxReg2Streetadd1,
                     EdtxReg2Streetadd2,
                     EdtxReg2City,
                     EdtxReg2Zipcode;

    private Spinner 
                    SpnrReg2Contry,
                    SpnrReg2Agent,
                    SpnrReg2State,
                    SpnrReg2PrimaryCurr,
                    SpnrReg2SecondaryCurr;

    private CustomParser cstParsr = new CustomParser();

    private String[] Regstrationstep1;
    private String[] strCountry,strProvince;
    private String[] Primarysecondarycur;
    private int globPosition;
    private String strSelecteccontry;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register2);
        GetDataFromLastPage();

        new FillSpinnerTask().execute();



    }

      private class FillSpinnerTask  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    Register2.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                this.dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.MsgPleasewait));
                this.dialog.show();
                this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
                // put your code which preload with processDialog

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // put your code here
                strCountry = cstParsr.LoadCountriesForMobApp(getApplicationContext());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
                if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                    try {
                        this.dialog.dismiss();
                        this.dialog = null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(strCountry != null)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<strCountry.length;i++)
                        {
                            Log.i("TAG","strCountry"+strCountry[i]);
                        }

                    }
                    FillView();

                }
            }
        }


    private void FillView() {

        BtnReg2Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnReg2Next);
        EdtxReg2Streetadd1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtxReg2Streetadd1);
        EdtxReg2Streetadd2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtxReg2Streetadd2);
        EdtxReg2City  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtxReg2City);
        EdtxReg2Zipcode =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtxReg2Zipcode);

        SpnrReg2Contry = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnrReg2Contry); 
        SpnrReg2Agent = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnrReg2Agent);
        SpnrReg2State = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnrReg2State);
        SpnrReg2PrimaryCurr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnrReg2PrimaryCurr);
        SpnrReg2SecondaryCurr= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnrReg2SecondaryCurr);


        if(strCountry != null)
        {
            ArrayAdapter languagelist = new ArrayAdapter(
                Register2.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                strCountry);

            languagelist.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            SpnrReg2Contry.setAdapter(languagelist);
        }


        SpnrReg2Contry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
           {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long arg3) 
                {   

                        strSelecteccontry = strCountry[position];
                        new FillProvinceSpinnerTask().execute();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }


            });

        /*SpnrReg2State.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(strProvince == null)
                {
                new FillProvinceSpinnerTask().execute();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });*/



        BtnReg2Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(EdtxReg2Streetadd1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")|
                     EdtxReg2Streetadd2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")|
                     EdtxReg2City.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")|
                     EdtxReg2Zipcode.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),getString(R.string.nullmessage),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else
                {
                     Intent Registration2 = new Intent(Register2.this,Register3.class);
                     startActivity(Registration2);
                     finish();
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void GetDataFromLastPage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Regstrationstep1 = new String[9];
        Regstrationstep1 = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Regstrationstep1");


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int Pos, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private class FillProvinceSpinnerTask  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                Register2.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.MsgPleasewait));
            this.dialog.show();
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            // put your code which preload with processDialog

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // put your code here
            strProvince = cstParsr.LoadProvinceFromCountryForMobApp(getApplicationContext(),strSelecteccontry);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                try {
                    this.dialog.dismiss();
                    this.dialog = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(strProvince != null)
                {


                    Primarysecondarycur = strProvince[0].split("~");
                    strProvince[0] = "Please Select a State";
                ArrayAdapter languagelist = new ArrayAdapter(
                        Register2.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                        strProvince);

                languagelist.setDropDownViewResource(
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                SpnrReg2State.setAdapter(languagelist);


                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the issue? logcat error?

Comment: when the page is load there are spinner "A" s item is load and also load spinner b item at a time with spinnerA[0] index bydefault

Comment: my basic requirement is when i select the item of spinner "A" it will load all item of Spinner "b"

Comment: the above code does not work? or if it works, what does it not do of your desires? because, on first preview, even if the code is not refactored, it seems to do the job.

Comment: No, as i told that there is problem when oncreat call it will automatically call `setOnClickListener` ans pass data on 0 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with OnItemSelectedListener is that it selects first value on declaration. To avoid the first call do something like this :

```
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(...);
        ...
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                if(count>0) {
                    // do what you want on item selection
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
```